Can you create a Visualforce Page that fills the entire document body?

I've created a test Visualforce page in a test app.
Is it possible to setup your own page without this standard Salesforce header at the top? So no tabs, global search or setup icons - just an empty page that I can add all of my custom HTML, CSS and Javascript to?
I can't find anything on this. There are pages in standard Salesforce that don't have this header such as Lightning App Builder and Flow Builder, but I'm not sure if we can create such pages as consumers of the platform.

Well, there's the showHeader attribute in the <apex:page> tag, and that works when the VF page is kinda more "standalone". Having this be in the header bar for an app means things probably work differently. Not having that header bar means that once you get into that page, you wouldn't be able to leave it (without clicking the back button in the browser, or you explicitly providing a working link out of that page). This sounds like an X-Y Problem. What's the bigger picture here? What will having the entire screen do for you?

Yeah that's all I need actually haha, if I access the the page standalone (by linking directly to the page '.../apex/test'), then I can provide a complete custom experience there and provide my own navigation links out of if needed (dunno why I couldn't think of this). Thank you. I just want to build a totally custom frontend experience within Salesforce, that depends on various metadata records, but want to uise Vanilla JS and not LWC, so VF seems to be the way to go with Javascript Remoting

This approach is far less flexible than using LWC based UI. We have moved away from it. One of the huge benefits of using LWCs is the ability to embed screen flows.

@Phil W, I get it, LWC is the way front end dev is done now in SF, and it's compatible with many other areas of the platform. Setting that aside, say you do wan't to build a more native Javascript application that talks more directly with the DOM, and you know that this app would never need to embed screen flows or any other features only available through LWC - then would using VF be the best way to  contain such an app?
I'm not talking about using the server side rendering features of VF - it would just be replying on JavaScript Remoting as an abstraction for XMLHttpRequests

I wouldn't go this route myself. You can manage your own DOM in an LWC if you really need to (though again I would avoid doing this as you cannot benefit from improvements Salesforce provide for Lightning Experience if you roll your own from the ground up. It is also a lot harder to do sophisticated stuff using VFRemoting (though you can benefit from not having any boxcarring by ensuring buffering is turned off).
